# Is it possible to use Unix commands to cp a file in my subdirectory into a remote computer via SSH?

Tags: ssh, remote

I have a series of software files downloaded into my subdirectory `~/Downloads` on my personal computer. I am also using bash to connect remotely to a computer using `ssh`.

Is it possible to transfer this file via `ssh` to the remote computer?

Comment: The question refers to a singular file (`this file`) and multiple files (`a series of software files`), the best solution depends upon whether you have a single file or multiple files.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may want to use `scp` for this purpose. It is a secure means to transfer files using the SSH protocol.

For example, to copy a file named `yourfile.txt` from `~/Downloads` to remote computer, use:

```
scp ~/Downloads/yourfile.txt your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory
```

You can see more examples [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

Comment: I think `rsync` may work as well, now that I think about it

Comment: rsync is far to complex for just one or a hand full of files...

Comment: @Paebbels On the contrary, replace `scp` above with `rsync` and it should work just fine.

Comment: I tend to use `rsync` for everything, even single files, because it "just works" in the simple cases and can be far more efficient in other cases. If using either `scp` or `rsync` on anything not already compressed and/or encrypted, remember to turn the compression option on (`-C` for `scp`, `-z` or `--compress` for `rsync`). In fact I turn it on by habit - it is very rare you'll find a circumstance where it ever slows things down (perhaps if you are using a slow low-power device with limited CPI power like an rPi).

Answer (score 37):

Though `scp` is clearly the right tool for this, if for some reason you can't use it you could do something like the following from your local machine to copy, say, a directory structure to the remote machine:

```
tar -c . | ssh <remote> tar -x
```

This will `tar` the current directory on the local machine, and write that `tar` to `stdout` which will then be piped to an `ssh` command where it will execute a remote command to untar the file it reads from `stdin`

Edited to reflect Dietrich Epp's comment about `-f -` being the default on both the creation and extraction ends, so not being necessary to specify explicitly.

Comment: You'll probably want to add a `-C basedir` argument to `tar` to extract somewhere other than your home directory if you're doing this.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to do this on more than the rare occasion, I'd suggest mounting the remote filesystem with `sshfs` if you are using a Unix-like that supports FUSE (Linux, *BSD, Mac OS X).  Make a directory under your home directory, say, called ~/remote-server:

```
    $ mkdir ~/remote-server
```

Then mount the remote filesystem with `sshfs`.  Replace "yourserver.com" with the host name of your remote machine, and "name of remote directory" with the directory you are using on the remote system.

```
    $ sudo sshfs username@yourserver.com:/name/of/remote/directory ~/remote-server/
```

Once this is done, the remote directory is part of your filesystem and you can use all your normal tools on it, including `cp`:

```
    $ cp ~/Downloads/your-files ~/remote-server
```

If you don't already have `sshfs` installed, you should be able to install it on your computer using your package manager (look for packages named `sshfs` or `fuse-sshfs`). For more information, you can read [a tutorial online](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-mount-remote-directory-filesystems-with-sshfs-on-linux/).

This, by the way, is my favorite way of managing files on remote servers.  I normally keep one production server and two development servers mounted in this way and use my normal file browsing workflow with them.

Comment: And then check which sshfs options will help you get your work best done. E.g. starting with user/group ID mapping `-o idmap={none,user,file},gid=<remote_user_group_ID>,allow_other` and `-C` for compression if poor bandwith. As soon as it works good, I personally add aliases for the commands to quickly mount the distant filesystems over ssh. @Benjamin_Staton I wouldn't use sudo or root here, not without a proper user/group mapping at least.

Answer (score 9):

First time, there is no real difference between `scp` (copy over `ssh`) and `rsync`.

Subsequent runs will benefit by rsync not copying files that already exist.

```
rsync -avH ~/Downloads  username@remotehost:Downloads
```

- `-a` for all files
- `-v` for verbose
- `-H` for "just figure out symlinks and do the right thing"
- then source and destination paths.  You can use wildcards in the source, or just sync the whole directory.

Other useful flags include:

- `--delete`    to delete files in the destination that no-longer exist on the source.
- `--dry-run`    for testing - very handy when combined with `--delete`.

This will use `ssh` keys to do a passwordless login too, if you have them set up.

At the end of the run, `rsync` will tell you how many times faster it was over doing the plain copy over again.

Comment: `-H` is actually for hard links, it stops the same content being sent twice or more when it is linked into more than one place in the source directory structure (but can make the process less efficient for large directory structures). it has no effect on symbolic links, but some of the options included by `-a`/`--archive` do affect how symlinks are processed.

Answer (score 4):

To add to above answers. Sometimes I am not exactly sure about remote path. In these cases I use `sftp` to first navigate to required location, then use get or put to actually download or upload a file.

If you also want to keep something always synced and even want to execute locally some file that is located on remote machine, `sshfs` works great.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing something very similar with ssh. I created a custom build tool for Visual Studio and am basically having VS run an ssh command that copies my code to a target computer and then compiles it on that target computer.

> ssh userB@hostB 'cp /network/path/of/source/file.ext /path/of/final/file.ext; ./runCustomCommand'

Notice the use of single quote mark and semi-colon. The former encapsulates your commands to hostB via ssh and the latter allows you to run multiple hostB system commands in one ssh command from hostA.

In order to make this work, you'll need to set up ssh keys on your start machine so that you can be userA@hostA and login to hostB as userB. The process for creating a public ssh key for userA@hostA is well documented.
If you don't create a public key on hostA for userA, and copy that key to hostB as userB, then you'll be forced to enter your password every time - which ruins the joy of automation.

Comment: Can anyone who downvoted leave a comment as to why they downvoted? Down votes are meaningless without informative feedback.Thanks.

I have addressed the OP's specific question with an answer that directly relates. I'm not introducing new technology or suggesting alternate routes. Why? maybe OP doesn't want to use alternate routes.